# Does emailing through AWS SES still depend on email hosting's daily number of emails limit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses, godaddy-api

I have email hosting with GoDaddy, with only one account. GoDaddy email has a limit of 250 emails per day.

Now, AWS SES can do up to 50000 emails per day.

So here is my question:
**If I send out emails using AWS SES with my GoDaddy email address, would GoDaddy email daily limit still apply? OR would I be able to deliver up to 50000 emails per day?**

Thank you in advance for answering my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you send emails using AWS SES then GoDaddy is no longer part of the picture and it's limit can be ignored. SES provides is providing its' own infrastructure to send emails and doesn't rely on Godaddy.

In the case of AWS SES there are some limits to be aware of

1. You can only send emails from domains you own.

   - You will need to verify that you own the domain you wish to send emails from.
2. Emails must be less than 10MB
3. The number of emails you can send is determined by 2 factors:

   - Sending limit: the maximum number of recipients that you can send email to in a 24-hour period.
   - Maximum send rate: the maximum number of recipients that you can send email per second.

You may find this page helpful: https://aws.amazon.com/ses/faqs/